# Dash in Environment Name

Tags: environments, fancyvrb

I'm trying to make a verbatim environment called "my-environ"

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{myenviron}{Verbatim}{numbers=left,frame=lines,label=My Environ,labelposition=topline}

%\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{my-environ}{Verbatim}{numbers=left,frame=lines,label=My-Environ,labelposition=topline}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenviron}
Hello
\end{myenviron}

%\begin{my-environ}
%Hello
%\end{my-environ}

\end{document}
```

If you uncomment the code, you'll see that it doesn't compile. I don't have to use `fancyvrb`, but I would like similar functionality.

Comment: Because dashes are not allowed in *control words* (control sequences consisting of an escape character and followed by one or more letters), dashes are not allowed in environment names either. Suggestion: use `myEnviron` instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In his [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172535/16967) egreg has already explained that the hyphen `-` has a different catcode inside the verbatim environment. Package `fancyvrb` saves the environment name from `\begin{my-environ}` in `\FV@EnvironName`. `-` has the catcode *before* the catcode changes of the verbatim environment, usually 12 (other). Then inside the environment `fancyvrb` looks for `\end{...}` and checks if `...` matches `\FV@EnvironName`. But `-` has now catcode 13 (active) and the strings `my-environ` does not match because of the different catcode of `-` and `fancyvrb` fails to see the end of the environment.

The example hacks the macros of `fancyvrb` to define `\FV@EnvironCheckName` that stores `my-environ` with the catcodes of the verbatim environment.
The hack requires e-TeX because of `\scantokens`, `\everyeof`, and `\unexpanded` to get the unexpanded environment name with the catcodes, which are active after the catcode settings of the verbatim environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{my-environ}{Verbatim}{
  numbers=left,
  frame=lines,
  label=My-Environ,
  labelposition=topline,
}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\VerbatimEnvironment}{%
  \ifx\FV@EnvironName\relax
    \xdef\FV@EnvironName{\@currenvir}%
    \begingroup
      \endlinechar=-1 %
      \everyeof{\@nil\noexpand}%
      \xdef\FV@EnvironCheckName{%
        \expandafter
        \FV@CatchUnexpanded\scantokens\expandafter{\@currenvir}%
      }%
    \endgroup
  \fi
}
\def\FV@CatchUnexpanded#1\@nil{\unexpanded{#1}}
\begingroup
\catcode`\^^M=\active
\gdef\FancyVerbGetLine#1^^M{%
  \@nil%
  \FV@CheckEnd{#1}%
  \ifx\@tempa\FV@EnvironCheckName%            % True if end is found
    \ifx\@tempb\FV@@@CheckEnd\else\FV@BadEndError\fi%
    \let\next\FV@EndScanning%
  \else%
    \def\FV@Line{#1}%
    \def\next{\FV@PreProcessLine\FV@GetLine}%
  \fi%
  \next%
}%
\endgroup
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{my-environ}
Hello
\end{my-environ}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 16):

The problem is quite subtle. In general, a hyphen is allowed to be in an environment name, just like any other non special character (and also some special ones, actually). However, it's not possible to use some of them in a verbatim environment, because the verbatim mode makes them *active*; in `latex.ltx` you find

```
\def\verbatim@nolig@list{\do\`\do\<\do\>\do\,\do\'\do\-}
```

and the characters in the list, that is `` `<,'- `` are made active in order (La)TeX not make the usual ligatures

```
?` !` << >> ,, `` '' -- ---
```

However, the end of your `verbatim` environment is delimited by a *string*

```
\end{my-verbatim}
```

which `fancyvrb` builds before setting the active characters above. A string in the sense that all characters have category code 12; `fancyvrb` loads a line at the time and compares it to the ending string. However, if the name of the environment contains one of the characters above, the ending string can't be found.

It's maybe possible to hack the macros so that those characters are allowed, but the best is to use only letters.

Comment: This is good to know! (I realize the question seems crazy)